# Is there a check to get if eSim/project FI is being used

Tags: android, telephonymanager, google-project-fi

In Android there is a system broadcast being sent when the SIM card changes: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED. If the phone is configured with an eSIM e.g. over Project FI from Google, this broadcast is being triggered each time the phone connects to another carrier, so is there a way to check if the broadcast is triggered because of eSIM and distinguish this from real SIM changes?